# Haskell - Iterate and Populate list

Tags: list, loops, haskell

I am very new to haskell, and it's by far the hardest language I found to wrap my mind around. I've found a past paper online and I decided to try to implement this in haskell for practice.

I have a list of integers like the following in myFile.txt:

```
5
3 30
10 120
80 96
95 96
98 98
```

Where the First number in the list has an integer to tell me how many tests will follow. In this case, 5 will follow.

I am trying to return a single number(eg: 20) for each test(eg: 3 30) that signifies the total multiples that are in a particular range.

As an example of the first test, 3 30:

1. I need to find the multiples of each number from 2 to the first number (In this case, 2 and 3), up to the value 30. In this case:

   Multiples of 2: [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30]

   Multiples of 3: [3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30]
2. I then find what are similar and then count all unique values:

   [2,3,4,6,8,9,10,12,14,15,16,18,20,21,22,24,26,27,28,30]

The Size of the final list in number 2 is 20, and that's the value I would like to return

With that being said, I have ideas on how to do this implementation. My plans to do this implementation are:

1. Populate a single list with values that are multiples of numbers
   that are lesser and equal to the first number received.
2. Take the populated list, and group it.
3. Take the Length of group, and
   print the value.

To Start, I've done the following to read all the input, store into a list and pass it to a function to print it to confirm that I've received the right value:

```
main = do  
    let myList = []
    handle <- openFile "myFile.txt" ReadMode
    contents <- hGetContents handle
    let singlewords = words contents
        myList = f singlewords
    printMyVals myList
    hClose handle

f :: [String] -> [Integer]
f = map read


printMyVals :: [Integer] -> IO()
printMyVals myList = 
    print myList
```

At this point, I am stuck.

I am trying to figure out how I can iterate the values of my list, and use those values to populate another list with it's multiples, like stated above.

Any help on this?

Comment: as you know how to read and print, it would make sense to omit it from question. Could you express your problem just in ghci?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there's a few parts to this, and if you break them down to each step each one is fairly straightforward. Where the input per line is `m` and `n`:

1. Find all multiples of two between 2 and `n`
2. Find all multiples of `m` between `m` and `n`
3. Sort the two lists together, removing duplicates
4. Get the length of the resulting list and print it

Steps 1 and 2 are handled in the same function:

```
multiplesOfN n = [n, n+n..]
```

This will build an infinite list of values of multiples. Apply `takeWhile (<=x)` to get the capped values. For the first line of your input, you would have:

```
twos   = takeWhile (<=30) . multiplesOfN $ 2
threes = takeWhile (<=30) . multiplesOfN $ 3
```

Then you'll need to merge the two lists together, removing duplicates. Since they are both ascending lists, this is easy to do in a one-step mergesort.

```
mergesort :: (Eq a, Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
mergesort [] ys = ys
mergesort xs [] = xs
mergesort xss@(x:xs) yss@(y:ys)
  | x < y     = x : mergesort xs yss
  | otherwise = y : mergesort xss ys
-- but this doesn't remove duplicates! Let's deal with that by
-- adding a new argument @lastValue@ and discarding if any match

uniqMergesort :: (Eq a, Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
uniqMergesort xs [] = xs
uniqMergesort [] ys = ys
uniqMergesort xss@(x:xs) yss@(y:ys)
  | x < y     = x : go x xs  yss
  | otherwise = y : go y xss ys
  where
  go _ [] [] = []
  go lastValue (x:xs) []
    | lastValue == x =     go lastValue xs []
    | otherwise      = x : go lastValue xs []
  go lastValue [] (y:ys)
    | lastValue == y =     go lastValue [] ys
    | otherwise      = y : go lastValue [] ys
  go lastValue xss@(x:xs) yss@(y:ys)
    | x < y     = if   x == lastValue
                  then     go lastValue xs yss
                  else x : go x         xs yss
    | otherwise = if   y == lastValue
                  then     go lastValue xss ys
                  else y : go y         xss ys
```

Getting the length of the resulting list is just `length`, and pulling values from the file is splitting into lines, then words, then reading each word.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  handle <- openFile "myFile.txt" ReadMode
  contents <- hGetContents handle
  let inputs  = map (map read . words) . lines $ tail contents
      results = [let xs = takeWhile (<=n) . multiplesOfN $ 2
                     ys = takeWhile (<=n) . multiplesOfN $ m
                 in  uniqMergesort xs ys | [m, n] <- inputs]
  mapM_ (print . length) results
  hClose handle
```

Comment: Thanks for the info @Adam Smith
When trying to run this, I get the error when running the main function:


"multi - st - overflow.hs:(36,3)-(42,46): Non-exhaustive patterns in function go"
Line 36:   go lastValue xss@(x:xs) yss@(y:ys)
Line 42:   else y : go y         xss ys

Any idea what would be this issue?

Comment: @singher Your code or your example input must differ from what was given, then. See [my runnable example on repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/GrowlingMushyOpengroup)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I made an error in the code indeed and I tried your example and it works now, however, there may be a small logic error inside.
I find that the second test, yours reports 67  vs when I manually test it, I have 93 Unique multiples. I am trying to find the logic error inside.

Comment: @singher What's the input that gives 67? It's not included in your test inputs.

Comment: The input: 10 120  - the return is 67

Comment: @singher the return is 60 there, and it should be 60 (since `10 = 2*5`, all `x` where `x = 10n` are also factors of 2, so the result is just `length [2, 4..120]` which is trivially 60).

Comment: Hmm, So maybe It's slight different.
The idea would be to get all multiples up to the first number. In Second test with  10 120.

Multiples of 2[2,4,6,8,10,12 ... 120]
Multiples of 3[3,6,9,12,15,18,... 120]
Multiples of 4[4,8,12,16,20,24,28...120]
Until Multiples of 10 [10,20,30,40...120]

I then merger them all for Unique values only.

Does that make sence?

Comment: @singher oh! That's not the code I wrote (I only checked 2s and 10s in this case). Consider `let numbers = [[i, i+i..n] | i <- [2..m]] in foldr uniqMergeSort [] numbers`

Comment: Is this a change within the main? "results =  .." ?

Comment: Oh excellent, looks like this works indeed now. Thanks very much.
One last question if you dont mind. What if I wanted this to work with an extremely large number, for instance, a test like: 2 1000000000000000  - how would a test like this be able to pass?

Comment: You'd probably have to derive something arithmetically to find the total number of factors. Otherwise arbitrarily large inputs take arbitrarily long to process (as it should be)